# подсветка элементов меню

Tags: css, меню

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при переходе с пункта меню первого уровня в подменю второго уровня, пункт меню первого уровня оставался бы подсвеченным?

```
<div class="header-deep-0">
  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#0" class="here">
    <div class="header-deep-0__icon">
      <img src="/upload/iblock/264/01_obshchetekhnicheskie-i-estestvenno-nauchnye-distsipliny.svg">
    </div>
    <span class="left-menu-section-name">
    <span style="display: block;">
      Общетехнические и естественно научные дисциплины</span>
    </span>
    <span class="arrow glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
  </a>
</div>

<div id="0" class="panel-collapse collapse in">

  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="panel-group" id="0_nested">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="header-deep-1">
          <a href="/catalog/fizika">
            Физика </a>
        </div><!--/.panel-heading -->
        <div id="1_1" data-level="2" class="body-deep-1 panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="header-deep-2">

              <a href="/catalog/gotovye_laboratorii_po_fizike_mekhanike_optike" data-level="3" class="link-deep-2"> Лаборатории по физике, механике, оптике </a>
            </div>

          <div class="header-deep-2">

            <a href="/catalog/fizika_elektrichestvo_i_magnetizm" data-level="3" class="link-deep-2"> Физика-Электричество и магнетизм </a>
          </div>
```

Comment: Во-первых, размесите так же ваш css код. Во-вторых, хорошо бы создать в снипете, на jsfiddle или codepen модель, с которой можно было бы работать над ответом.

Comment: честно говоря, получилась полная вакханалия, не знаю поможет ли это

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWzQJv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Честно говоря там такая вакханалия, что до ума доводить не стал, но в целом думаю принцип ясен - [Pen](http://codepen.io/MedvedevDev/pen/jBJgVY)

1) Меняем местами выпадающий список и пункт его открывающий (.panel-collapse и .header-deep-0)

2) По хаверу на подменю дублируем стили хавера пункта который его открывает

```
.panel-collapse:hover + .header-deep-0 > a {
  background: #2b79c2;
  color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: А вообще, судя по классам, все хаверы управляются ещё и js'ом (.panel-collapse.collapse.in), но его предоставлено не было, по этому посчитаем, что его нет и будем отталкивать именно от того, что задачу надо решить на чистом css.

Comment: спасибо большое =)

Comment: а если бы я вам скинул код js, смогли бы вы подсказать, как сделать это через него?

Comment: Зависит от кода ))) Ну скорее всего да, почему бы и нет, по сути тут просто надо разобраться когда и как добавляются модификаторы, если js позволит их использовать, то накидать логику css по этим модификаторам не будет особой проблемой

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWzQJv добавил js)

Comment: Ничего не понимаю ... Ты скинул js, но он нерабочий, так как не подключен ни jQuery, ни Bootstrap. При чем погуглив (не фанат бутстрапа, не знаю что там за плагины), узнал, что ты используешь плагин Collapse из-за него и появились эти классы которые меня изначально смутили, так как они ничего не выполняют (в твоем коде), дефакто же, при правильм использовании плагина у тебя будет работать по идее как положено, где класс collapsed - будет означать скрытый контент, а класс, а класс in - как раз то что ищешь, то есть это класс показывающий, что пункт меню открыт и ты его можешь стилизовать

Comment: В общем советую тебе просто изучить плагин который ты используешь, например тут: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse_plugin.htm

Comment: хочешь что бы открывалось по хаверу, а не по клику, то либо ищи варианты в самом плагине, либо не используй его вовсе, у тебя используется плагин который делает все что тебе надо, но ты игнорируешь полностью и в итоге у тебя зачем-то открывается все по хаверу с помощью доп. кода и css ... это неправильный подход.

Answer (score 0):

**Решение с использованием Jquery:**

```
 $("Селектор").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).closest("селектор уровнем выше").css({'Значение' :'Свойство'});
        },

        function() {
            $(this).closest("селектор уровнем выше").css({'Значение' :'Свойство'});

        });
```

По порядку:

```
    $("Селектор").hover :
```

С помощью селектора(работают так же,как в css) указываем,при наведении на какие элементы мы хотим изменять ближайшего "родителя" этих элементов.

Затем у нас две функции.Первая применяется когда мы наводим на элементы,вторая - когда убираем от них курсор.

```
$(this).closest("селектор уровнем выше").css({'Значение' :'Свойство'});
```

Здесь мы указываем селектор элемента выше уровнем,а функция выберет ближайший выбранный нами элемент и применит к нему указанные css свойства.

Тоже самое для второй функции.
В первой - мы применяем нужные нам свойства при наведении, а во второй - мы возвращаем их в состояние до наведения ,либо применяем стандартные свойства.